# Docker extremadamente lento en windows

Tags: windows, docker

¿Existe la posibilidad de que docker vaya rápido en Windows? Agregué wsl2, configuré la memoria RAM y demás, pero no funciona muy bien, es muy lento. ¿Me puedes recomendar algo? ¡Gracias!

Comment: Hola, te recomiendo que pongas tu pregunta en español para que los usuarios de esta comunidad puedan ayudarte (Recuerda que estás en stackoverflow en español)

Comment: Yo tuve el mismo problema y al parecer fue la distro que descargue de la Store, en especifico hay dos distros de ubuntu pero la oficial la que sube canonical es la que esta mejor optimizada ya que hay otra y es con la que tuve problemas, reinstale y funciono mejor